# Not annotated parameter overrides @NonNull parameter: Where shall I put the solution Code?

Tags: java, android

I am trying a basic program for sending SMS from android app. But now when I run the app, nothing happens after clicking send sms button. I see no error message.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] 
    permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //return;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please post code as text, not as image. There's one question in the title and another problem in the body text. Which one is the issue you want help with?

Comment: This is my first time posting a query, I'll try to be more specific. And Thank You for your reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Read about [**`onRequestPermissionsResult()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html#onRequestPermissionsResult(int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[]))

You need to pass `NonNull` parameters in `onRequestPermissionsResult()`

**Parameters**

- **`requestCode int`**: The request code passed in
- **`permissions String`**: The requested permissions. **Never null.**
- **`grantResults  int`**: The grant results for the corresponding permissions which is either `PERMISSION_GRANTED` or `PERMISSION_DENIED`. **Never null.**

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, now I am not getting warning "not annotated-parameter-overrides-nonnull-parameter". But my app dont gives an output, whether expected or non-expected output.

Comment: Checked and run my program in 'Debug-app' mode, I am running my app in my device with Android OS version 4.4.2. I enter mobile number and a short text message in the next input text-field, but clicking on 'send SMS' button doesn't make any difference. Can't fetch what am I missing.

Comment: @DevP  have u added permission in manifest file and run time permission on only asked in Api 23 and above

Comment: Yes, I have added permission in manifest file, but I don't get asked for run time permission for API, API level of my mobile OS version is 19, does it make any difference? I get a message 'Instance Run is not supported on devices with API level lower than 20'

Comment: @DevP yes, run time permission for AP only asked in android marshmallow and above